# How to add songs to album entity in springboot?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postman

Please help me with the logic.
Is it possible to save data in multiple entities simultaneously? I f yes then how?
Also I have to do same with the singer entity i.e. add singer data to song entity...does it require the same logic or a different one.
The code for entities is as follows:

**Album entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums")
public class AlbumEntity extends ApplicationPersistenceEntity implements Album {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "album_id")
  @NotNull
  private long albumId;

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String albumName;

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(name = "Genre")
  private String genre;

  @Column(name = "album_release_date", columnDefinition = "DATE", nullable = false)
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Date albumreleaseDate;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id", nullable = false)
  private SingerEntity singer;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "album")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private List<SongEntity> songs;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The constructor.
   */
  public AlbumEntity() {

  }

  /**
   * The constructor.
   *
   * @param albumId
   * @param albumName
   * @param genre
   * @param albumreleaseDate
   * @param singer
   * @param songs
   */
  public AlbumEntity(long albumId, String albumName, String genre, Date albumreleaseDate, SingerEntity singer,
      List<SongEntity> songs) {

    super();
    this.albumId = albumId;
    this.albumName = albumName;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.albumreleaseDate = albumreleaseDate;
    this.singer = singer;
    this.songs = songs;
  }

  /**
   * @return albumId
   */
  @Override
  public long getAlbumId() {

    return this.albumId;
  }

  /**
   * @param albumId new value of {@link #getalbumId}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setAlbumId(long albumId) {

    this.albumId = albumId;
  }

  /**
   * @return albumName
   */
  @Override
  public String getAlbumName() {

    return this.albumName;
  }

  /**
   * @param albumName new value of {@link #getalbumName}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {

    this.albumName = albumName;
  }

  /**
   * @return genre
   */
  @Override
  public String getGenre() {

    return this.genre;
  }

  /**
   * @param genre new value of {@link #getgenre}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setGenre(String genre) {

    this.genre = genre;
  }

  /**
   * @return albumreleaseDate
   */
  @Override
  public Date getAlbumreleaseDate() {

    return this.albumreleaseDate;
  }

  /**
   * @param albumreleaseDate new value of {@link #getalbumreleaseDate}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setAlbumreleaseDate(Date albumreleaseDate) {

    this.albumreleaseDate = albumreleaseDate;
  }

  /**
   * @return singer
   */
  public SingerEntity getSinger() {

    return this.singer;
  }

  /**
   * @param singer new value of {@link #getsinger}.
   */
  public void setSinger(SingerEntity singer) {

    this.singer = singer;
  }

  /**
   * @return songs
   */
  public List<SongEntity> getSongs() {

    return this.songs;
  }

  /**
   * @param songs new value of {@link #getsongs}.
   */
  public void setSongs(List<SongEntity> songs) {

    this.songs = songs;
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public Long getSingerId() {

    if (this.singer == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.singer.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSingerId(Long singerId) {

    if (singerId == null) {
      this.singer = null;
    } else {
      SingerEntity singerEntity = new SingerEntity();
      singerEntity.setId(singerId);
      this.singer = singerEntity;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    return "AlbumEntity [albumId=" + this.albumId + ", albumName=" + this.albumName + ", genre=" + this.genre
        + ", albumreleaseDate=" + this.albumreleaseDate + ", singer=" + this.singer + ", songs=" + this.songs + "]";
  }

}
```

**Song entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
public class SongEntity extends ApplicationPersistenceEntity implements Song {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "song_id")
  // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  private long songId;

  @Column(name = "Title")
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "duration")
  private float duration;

  /**
   * @return duration
   */
  @Override
  public float getDuration() {

    return this.duration;
  }

  /**
   * @param duration new value of {@link #getduration}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setDuration(float duration) {

    this.duration = duration;
  }

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id", nullable = false)
  private SingerEntity singer;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "album_id")
  private AlbumEntity album;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The constructor.
   */
  public SongEntity() {

  }

  /**
   * The constructor.
   *
   * @param songId
   * @param title
   * @param content
   * @param singer
   * @param album
   */
  public SongEntity(long songId, String title, SingerEntity singer, AlbumEntity album) {

    super();
    this.songId = songId;
    this.title = title;
    this.singer = singer;
    this.album = album;
  }

  /**
   * @return songId
   */
  @Override
  public long getSongId() {

    return this.songId;
  }

  /**
   * @param songId new value of {@link #getsongId}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setSongId(long songId) {

    this.songId = songId;
  }

  /**
   * @return title
   */
  @Override
  public String getTitle() {

    return this.title;
  }

  /**
   * @param title new value of {@link #gettitle}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setTitle(String title) {

    this.title = title;
  }

  /**
   * @return singer
   */
  public SingerEntity getSinger() {

    return this.singer;
  }

  /**
   * @param singer new value of {@link #getsinger}.
   */
  public void setSinger(SingerEntity singer) {

    this.singer = singer;
  }

  /**
   * @return album
   */
  public AlbumEntity getAlbum() {

    return this.album;
  }

  /**
   * @param album new value of {@link #getalbum}.
   */
  public void setAlbum(AlbumEntity album) {

    this.album = album;
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public Long getSingerId() {

    if (this.singer == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.singer.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setSingerId(Long singerId) {

    if (singerId == null) {
      this.singer = null;
    } else {
      SingerEntity singerEntity = new SingerEntity();
      singerEntity.setId(singerId);
      this.singer = singerEntity;
    }
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public Long getAlbumId() {

    if (this.album == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.album.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setAlbumId(Long albumId) {

    if (albumId == null) {
      this.album = null;
    } else {
      AlbumEntity albumEntity = new AlbumEntity();
      albumEntity.setId(albumId);
      this.album = albumEntity;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    return "SongEntity [songId=" + this.songId + ", title=" + this.title + ", duration=" + this.duration + ", singer="
        + this.singer + ", album=" + this.album + "]";
  }

}
```

**Singer Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "singers")
public class SingerEntity extends ApplicationPersistenceEntity implements Singer {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "singer_id")
  private long singerId;

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(name = "singer_name")
  private String singerName;

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(name = "Gender")
  private String gender;

  @Column(name = "birth_date", columnDefinition = "DATE", nullable = false)
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Date birthDate;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "singer")
  private List<SongEntity> songs;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "singer")
  private List<AlbumEntity> albums;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The constructor.
   */
  public SingerEntity() {

  }

  /**
   * The constructor.
   *
   * @param singerId
   * @param firstname
   * @param lastname
   * @param gender
   * @param songs
   * @param albums
   */
  public SingerEntity(long singerId, String singerName, String gender, Date birthDate, List<SongEntity> songs,
      List<AlbumEntity> albums) {

    super();
    this.singerId = singerId;
    this.singerName = singerName;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.songs = songs;
    this.albums = albums;
  }

  /**
   * @return singerId
   */
  @Override
  public long getSingerId() {

    return this.singerId;
  }

  /**
   * @param singerId new value of {@link #getsingerId}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setSingerId(long singerId) {

    this.singerId = singerId;
  }

  /**
   * @return firstname
   */
  @Override
  public String getSingerName() {

    return this.singerName;
  }

  /**
   * @param singername new value of {@link #getsingername}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setSingerName(String singerName) {

    this.singerName = singerName;
  }

  /**
   * @return gender
   */
  @Override
  public String getGender() {

    return this.gender;
  }

  /**
   * @param gender new value of {@link #getgender}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setGender(String gender) {

    this.gender = gender;
  }

  /**
   * @return birthDate
   */
  @Override
  public Date getBirthDate() {

    return this.birthDate;
  }

  /**
   * @param birthDate new value of {@link #getbirthDate}.
   */
  @Override
  public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {

    this.birthDate = birthDate;
  }

  /**
   * @return songs
   */
  public List<SongEntity> getSongs() {

    return this.songs;
  }

  /**
   * @param songs new value of {@link #getsongs}.
   */
  public void setSongs(List<SongEntity> songs) {

    this.songs = songs;
  }

  /**
   * @return albums
   */
  public List<AlbumEntity> getAlbums() {

    return this.albums;
  }

  /**
   * @param albums new value of {@link #getalbums}.
   */
  public void setAlbums(List<AlbumEntity> albums) {

    this.albums = albums;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    return "SingerEntity [singerId=" + this.singerId + ", singerName=" + this.singerName + ", gender=" + this.gender
        + ", birthDate=" + this.birthDate + ", songs=" + this.songs + ", albums=" + this.albums + "]";
  }

}
```

I want to add songs to album table.
But I am not able to figure out the logic to do this.
I want that when I send data from post man like

```json
{
    "id": 102,
    "albumId": 102,
    "albumName": "HS1",
    "genre": "Pop",
    "singerId":202,

    "songs":[
        {
            "id": 302,
            "songId": 302,
            "title": "Bad blood",
            "singerId": 201,
            "duration": 3.76
        },
        {
            "id": 303,
            "songId": 303,
            "title": "Happy",
            "singerId": 202,
            "duration": 3.54
        }
    ],
    "albumreleaseDate":"2019-05-16"
}
```

Then the data should be saved in album and song table respectively
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOMRY.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused from your example data. First, I thought it's a POST for album, because it contains all the information of the album and singerID. Then I saw it also contains all information for the song. Which would imply that the song is also to be created.

So this is what I would do:

1. Create an album:

Request:

```json
POST /album

{
  "id": 1,
  "genre": "Pop",
  "name": "SomeFancyName",
  "singerId": 12,
  "songs": [
    3,
    5,
    6,
    15//...
  ]
}
```

Here you will verify the existence of all songs by their ID and return 404 if a song does not exist

Response:

```json
201 Created
Headers: Location: "/ablums/{albumId}"
```

2. Add songs to an album

Request:

```json
PATCH /album/{albumId}/songs

{
  "songs": [
    7,
    19,
    21,
    13//...
  ]
}
```

Again verify the existence of all songs by their ID and return 404 if a song does not exist.

Response:

```json
204 No Content
```

3. Delete song from album
   Same as 2. just use `DELETE` method instead of `PATCH`

---

Songs and Singer would get their own endpoints accordingly and you only reference them by their ids in requests. Because, when you do a POST on album and add full song data, you either also create the song and have to think about what to do if the song already exists or send unnecessary data since the id should be enough to identify the song.

Basically, you add too much complexity to one endpoint